# WCF Data Service: How to get the IP Address of Request?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

What is the best way to get the **IP Address** of **Request** in **Wcf Data Service**?

I am using .Net 4

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;

MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties; 

RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty; 

string ip = endpoint.Address;
```

Comment: Is your service on the localhost?

Comment: Yes the service is in localhost